# Adding pdf pages into latex

Tags: pdf

I am trying to insert a PDF file as an appendix in my latex file. But when I add the `\usepackage{pdfpages}`, I have some compiler errors as

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: \usepackage{pdfpages}

\includepdf[pages=-]{myfile.pdf}

Answer (score 7):

You have to follow the LaTeX structure with the following order:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{myfile.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: consider use `fitpaper=true` in your `\includepdf[fitpaper=true, pages=-]{test.pdf}` for a fully fit to the page